# What does Production Phase ,Development Phase and deployment means in Visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, svn, deployment

I am not looking for Definitions for all these terms but interested in knowing ***"How Developers work when they are developing some software in ASP.net"***

My senior has divided the project in 2 folders .first one is ***Development:D*** second is ***Subversion:S*** folder.Both folders contains same files.

While programming(development)on which folder should I work.( i mean on which file should I open to start programming : D folder or S folder ).
We are using ***Subversion*** and visual studio 2010.

If any one could explain me "Deployment scenario " then I would be very thankful to them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We use SVN at our site (TortoiseSVN as client).

Each project has its own repository with three types, a Trunk, a Releases branch, and Branches. Trunk is a work in progress, Releases are snapshots of the source for major releases, and a new Branch gets created for a particular task. Upon completion a branch will get merged back into Trunk, and eventually a release gets created from Trunk.

Development phase and Production phase seem confusing, but I'm guessing development means code in the process of being developed, and production means code that has been released into the production environment. You generally don't want to do development in the production environment, you should start in development phase and once the functionality is thoroughly tested, promote it to production.

Comment: Thanks for the answer .Makes me clear on development and Production.

Comment: Looking for more answers and if anyone could provide me some links where I can go and research myself on these topics.

Comment: You might research the "software development life cycle", it outlines the funamental concepts of developing, releasing, and supporting software.